# How to write two dataframes in different functions into one excel file in django

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app. In that app i have two functions in views. In each function, dataframe`enter code here` write data to excel file. But i want to write the data in one excel file.

But this way it only store df data i want both dataframe data into two sheets

```
def func_one(request):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    ad_dataframe.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()


def func_two(request):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dfs = {'Sheet 1':df1, 'Sheet 2':df2}
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

for sheet_name in dfs.keys():
    dfs[sheet_name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I want to two dataframes into one excel file and both dataframes are in different view functions @umesh how should i pass one exel writer to another function

Comment: @ApurvaKulkarni check updated solution. Get your dfs to one place and the write it to excel file. Does it help?

Comment: Yes this will work. Do you have any idea how to pass dataframe to other view function?

Comment: you can pass it as a normal argument like method(df). If you can put some code then we will get more idea and might help you more.

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
def func_one(request):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    ad_dataframe.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()


def func_two(request):
    book = load_workbook(file_path)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    ad_dataframe.to_excel(writer, "Sheet2",index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pandas?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Simple as:

```
df.to_excel(my_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write them with pandas to distinct sheets or even join them and write to a unique sheet in your excel file.

[Example write to multiple sheets](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)

Comment: i have created Excelwriter in one function and write dataframe in it but i do i pass that existing writer to another function?